# Displaying contour lines calculated from SRTM in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, contour, srtm

I'm relatively inexperienced in GIS, but would like to display contour lines calculated from SRTM data in Google Earth.

It doesn't matter whether they are actual linestrings or just an image overlay.

In a previous life, I worked with SRTM height files in Matlab, so I could probably botch a solution in Matlab or Scilab.

Is there a simple way to do this using free software?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] which leads on to the [help/on-topic] pages that describe the types of questions suitable for asking here.

Comment: Using a GIS software:

Convert your SRTM DEM file into contours, in ArcGIS the function is contour but I am sure there is an equivalent in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) (its an open software). When you generate your contours specify your desired interval.

Then export the contours files into KML format

Import the KML file you generated into google earth.

Comment: @yanes - the equivalent in QGIS is Raster -> Extraction -> Contour.

Answer (score 1):

Using a GIS software:

Convert your SRTM DEM file into contours, in ArcGIS the function is contour but I am sure there is an equivalent in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) (its an open software). When you generate your contours specify your desired interval.

Then export the contours files into a KML format

*From Juffy's comment above the QGIS equivalent of Contour is..`the equivalent in QGIS is Raster -> Extraction -> Contour.`